# Is it faster to use React.memo if the areEqualFunction performs complex/a large number of comparisons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

Say I have the following code:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ arrayOfStuff }) => (
  <div>
    {arrayOfStuff.map(element => (
      <p key={element.foo}>element.foo</p>
    ))}
  </div>
);

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  const prevArrayOfStuff = prevProps.arrayOfStuff;
  const nextArrayOfStuff = nextProps.arrayOfStuff;
  if (prevArrayOfStuff.length !== nextArrayOfStuff.length)
      return false;

  for (let i; i < prevArrayOfStuff.length && i < nextArrayOfStuff.length; ++i) {
    if (prevArrayOfStuff[i].foo !== nextArrayOfStuff[i].foo)
        return false;
  }

  return true;
};

export default memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

And suppose arrayOfStuff is pretty large, maybe hundreds of elements. Am I really saving much time memoizing the component? I would think that in the event the props are the same, it would iterate over all the elements regardless of the memo since both areEqual and the render function do so.

Comment: The best answer to this is: Profile it and see. :-) It'll vary a lot by what kinds of changes you make to the props over time.

Comment: The component you've shown has just  a *single* prop (the array). Is that accurate, or does it also have other props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer to this is: Profile it and see. :-)

But although your array may have hundreds of entries in it, the checks you're doing aren't complex, they're quite straightforward and quick. (I'd add an `if (prevArrayOfStuff === nextArrayOfStuff) { return true; }` at the beginning.)

Some pros and cons:

Pros:

- Your check is quite straightforward and fast, even for hundreds of elements.
- If you find no changes, you save:

  - Creating a bunch of objects (the React "element"s returned by the component).
  - React having to compare the keys of the previous elements with the new ones to see if it needs to update the DOM.
- Remember that your component will be called to re-render any time anything in its *parent* changes, even if those changes don't relate to your component.

Cons:

- If there *are* change in the array often, you're just adding more work for no reward because `areEqual` is going to return `false` anyway.
- There's ongoing maintenance cost to `areEqual`, and it presents opportunities for bugs.

So it really comes down to what changes in your overall app, and in particular the parents of your component. If those parents have state or props that change often but not related to your component, your component doing its check could save a lot of time.

Here's something demonstrating how your component will get called to re-render when something in its *parent* changed even though nothing in its props did:

**Without** memoizing it (React won't actually update DOM elements if nothing changes, but your function is called and creates the React elements that React compares to the rendered ones):

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

// A stand-in for your component
const Example = ({items}) => {
    console.log("Example rendering");
    return <div>
        {items.map(item => <span key={item}>{item}</span>)}
    </div>;
};

// Some other component
const Other = ({counter}) => {
    console.log("Other rendering");
    return <div>{counter}</div>;
};

// A parent component
const App = () => {
    // This changes every tick of our interval timer
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    // This changes only every three ticks
    const [items, setItems] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter(c => {
                c = c + 1;
                if (c % 3 === 0) {
                    // Third tick, change `items`
                    setItems(items => [...items, items.length + 1]);
                }
                // Stop after 6 ticks
                if (c === 6) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log("Done");
                    }, 0);
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
                return c;
            });
        }, 500);
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, []);
    
    return <div>
        <Example items={items} />
        <Other counter={counter} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 80% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

**With** memoizing it:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

// A stand-in for your component
const Example = ({items}) => {
    console.log("Example rendering");
    return <div>
        {items.map(item => <span key={item}>{item}</span>)}
    </div>;
};

const examplePropsAreEqual = ({items: prevItems}, {items: nextItems}) => {
    const areEqual = (
        prevItems === nextItems ||
        (
            prevItems.length === nextItems.length &&
            prevItems.every((item, index) => item === nextItems[index])
        )
     );
     if (areEqual) {
         console.log("(skipped Example)");
     }
     return areEqual;
}

const ExampleMemoized = React.memo(Example, examplePropsAreEqual);

// Some other component
const Other = ({counter}) => {
    console.log("Other rendering");
    return <div>{counter}</div>;
};

// A parent component
const App = () => {
    // This changes every tick of our interval timer
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    // This changes only every three ticks
    const [items, setItems] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter(c => {
                c = c + 1;
                if (c % 3 === 0) {
                    // Third tick, change `items`
                    setItems(items => [...items, items.length + 1]);
                }
                // Stop after 6 ticks
                if (c === 6) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log("Done");
                    }, 0);
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
                return c;
            });
        }, 500);
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, []);
    
    return <div>
        <ExampleMemoized items={items} />
        <Other counter={counter} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 80% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```